# Tkinter error(tkinter.TclError: bad geometry specifier "500*500)

Tags: python, tkinter

I got an error on st=Tk()

**And the error is tkinter.TclError**

Comment: line 2073, in wm_geometry
    return self.tk.call('wm', 'geometry', self._w, newGeometry)
_tkinter.TclError: bad geometry specifier "50*50"

Comment: Error that i got

Comment: It should be '500x500' not '500*500'

Answer (score 1):

it should be `root.geometry("500x500")`(root is the hypothetical window name)
but not `root.geometry("500*500")`